# Strategy to develop a cross platform app that displays a Qlikview dashboard

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, qlikview

This isn't exactly a programming question, it's more of a "how to approach this problem" question.
I have a *Qlikview* dashboard that I've created and uploaded on a server. I've created a Safari short cut that accesses this. I now need to create a dedicated app that displays just this dashboard. The dashboard opens up in Safari(on the iPad) and it needs a Windows Authentication to be viewed. 
Also, I wanted to create a login page for this app that will pass the credentials to this popup that appears on the browser so that the user doesn't need to enter the credentials repeatedly. Is there a way to do this?
I'd be grateful if somebody could suggest some ideas to accomplish this. And please do comment any further queries you might have, in case what I've mentioned wasn't clear enough.
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop a simple web application on .NET environment. It would have a login page and a dashboard page which you embed your qlikview document using iframe integration.

Once the user logins you will pass user details to qlik leveraging ticketing functionality, get a ticket(consisted of characters) and then forward user to the dashboard page. On the dashboard page you will have an iframe of which url is a purpose built address containing the ticket.

I advise you to have a look at the following links:

For webticket implementation: https://community.qlik.com/docs/DOC-3614

For Document integration: http://tools.qlikblog.at/QlikView-Mashups/QlikView_Mashups_1.html

Comment: Okay this is what has been implemented. But I have a kind of noob-ish doubt. The final display is done using a frameset. Not an iframe. If I change that to the iframe, will I be able to view the qlikview dashboard in the browser without the address bar showing up? A pseudo full screen almost?

Comment: if you display the document in a single iframe, you may see browser's address bar depending on the browser. However you can view a qlikivew document in full screen with the help of BigScreen.js. you can do this upon a button click. If this will help I can edit my answer and give more detail.

Comment: This does help, but is it possible to alter the js such that it functions on load? Or is it true that you can go fullscreen only on user action?

Comment: I tried but couldn't achieve to do that yet. Seems not possible.

Comment: I tried the same. It needs user action to go fullscreen. But this is the closest reply to an answer so I'll accept it.